# Configurar FTP no AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, ftp, sftp

preciso configurar o FTP de acesso às pastas dentro de /var/www em um servidor no AWS, utilizando o Filezilla.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Na AWS você vai precisar usar SFTP e no Filezilla informar a sua chave SSH de acesso à instância. Neste link existe um bom tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 2):

As instruções variam um pouco dependendo de qual distro você esteja usando (Ubuntu, Amazon Linux, CentOS, RedHat, etc.)

Estes são os passos que segui para configurar o serviço de SFTP em um sistema Ubuntu 14.04 há algumas semanas.

Crie um grupo para limitar o acesso ao FTP:

```
sudo addgroup ftpaccess
```

Ubuntu 14.04 ja vem com openssh-server instalado, se o seu sistema não vier, use: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Edite o arquivo */etc/ssh/sshd_config*. Procure esta linha:

```
#Subsystem sftp
```

E "descomente-a", deletando o `#`. Procure esta outra linha:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

E mude-a para:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Adicione o seguinte ao final do arquivo:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
  ChrootDirectory /var/www
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Salve o arquivo. E reinicie o OpenSSH com `sudo service ssh restart`.

Criando usuário com acesso ao FTP:

```
# criando usuario que não pode fazer login no sistema
sudo useradd -m myftpuser -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin
# escolhendo a senha desse usuário (o comando vai pedir para vc digitar a senha)
sudo passwd myftpuser
sudo chown myftpuser:ftpaccess /var/www
```

Como mudamos o dono e grupo do diretorio */var/www*, precisamos garantir que o web server também continue tendo access. Se você estiver usando Apache, isso deve ser suficiente:

```
sudo adduser www-data ftpaccess
```

Com essa configuração, deve ser fácil conectar via SFTP usando FileZilla ou qualquer outro programa. Exemplo:

- Usuário: myftpuser
- Senha: a que você digitou quando criou o usuário
- Host: IP de seu servidor
- Protocolo: SFTP (importante, diferente de FTP simples)
- Port: 22 (esse é o default para SFTP)